# Batch menu with function keys

Tags: batch-file, keyboard

Is it possible to use the Function keys as an option with Choice for a batch command input menu

```
f1 - app1
f2 - app2
f3 - app3
```

Comment: Batch command? First of all: What command interpreter are we talking about?

Comment: @leo, "batch-file" usually means windows batch.

Comment: from the tag's description "A batch file is a text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on DOS, OS/2, or Microsoft Windows systems."

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that this is possible with standard Windows commands and console applications.

A third-party console application would be required which waits for a function key press and sets an environment variable containing either the strings "F1", "F2", ... or the key code of the function key, or which exits with value 1, 2, ... or the key code of the function key which is assigned to environment variable **ERRORLEVEL**.

Such a tool would be easy to code for example in language **C**, but in my point of view is a waste of time because the keys 1, 2, 3 can be used also in a batch file and no additional tool needed.

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo Please select application to run with appropriate key:
echo.
echo    1 ... application X
echo.
echo    2 ... application Y
echo.
echo    3 ... application Z
echo.
echo Any other key results in exit without running an application.
echo.
set /P "AppChoice=Your choice: "
if "%AppChoice%"=="1" goto App1
if "%AppChoice%"=="2" goto App2
if "%AppChoice%"=="3" goto App3
goto :EOF

:App1
echo Starting application X ...
goto :EOF

:App2
echo Starting application Y ...
goto :EOF

:App3
echo Starting application Z ...
goto :EOF
```

It does not really matter for the user if key F1, F2, F3 or key 1, 2, 3 must be pressed.